# A question about the maximal subgroup of SO(n+1)?

Tags: lie-groups

Is SO(n) a maximal subgroup of SO(n+1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is properly contained in $S(O(n)\times O(1))$.

Comment: A check by hand on the Lie algebras shows that it is not contained in a proper subgroup of bigger dimension.

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by S(O(n)×O(1))?

Comment: This means block matrices $\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{pmatrix}$ where $A\in O(n),B\in O(1)$ and the whole matrix has determinant 1.

Comment: @ user75905 How can you prove it?